# Is it possible to insert a new row using a View with Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a view on my database and I am trying to add a new record using the AddTo method but it is not working. I noticed that LinqToEntities is creating the insert statement like this

```
Insert into (select field1, field2 from my_view) (field1, field2) values (value1, value2)
```

Is it possible to make LinqToEntities create the insert statement like the one below ?

```
Insert into my_view (field1, field2) values (value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is a known issue with Views in Entity Framework.

Check out [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2008/10/04/how-to-create-an-updateable-view-with-ado-entity-framework.aspx) for the workaround.

The **key sentence** from the blog:

> ADO Entity Framework (EF) makes views Read Only via the `<DefiningQuery>` element. You make the data model view update-able by removing the  element and making a few minor changes.